# Authenticate using LinkedIn in Angular 2

Tags: angular, linkedin-api

I am trying to authenticate user by using LinkedIn.
Following is my code

```
onLinkedInLoad() {

    IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", this.onLinkedInAuth);
}
public onLinkedInAuth() {

    IN.API.Profile("me")
        .fields("firstName", "lastName")
        .result(this.displayProfiles)
        .error(this.displayProfilesErrors);

}
public displayProfiles(profiles) {
    var linkedinmember = profiles.values[0];
    console.log(JSON.stringify(linkedinmember));
    console.log(linkedinmember.firstName + " " + linkedinmember.lastName);
}
public displayProfilesErrors(error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    console.log(error);
}

<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: 44tt5566yyyyy
    scope: r_emailaddress
</script>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="icon-linkedin" (click)="onLinkedInLoad()"></span>linkedin</a>
```

It is giving no error but linkedin signin window is not opening.

Comment: if the signing window is not opening ..that means that is not proper set..how you checked the console for errors?

Comment: I am using console.log(error.message); in error method but nothing is catching

Comment: I mean the terminal...

Comment: In chrome developer console

Comment: I dont know how your setup angular.. but if it was with angular cli.. your run the project with typing ng serve..with anguar seed npm start ..that terminal is what I mean

Comment: I am not getting any error in cli

Comment: How should i debug?